# Generate a power set by only adding or removing a single element at a time

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Is there an algorithm that is capable of generating a complete power set by only removing or adding one element in each step? I'd like it to avoid duplicates, but ordering isn't important. I've tried iterating over a set with four elements looking for a pattern that can be repeated to a larger set. I've found a dozen paths, but they seem to be random. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example with {x, y, z}: {} {x} {x, y} {y} {y, z} {z} {x, z} {x, y, z}

Starting with an empty set, every subsequent set is built by either adding or removing one element. I'd like to do this with larger sets predictably.

Comment: Are we talking about generating all the elements of the powerset of a *finite* set, for example with some computer application ?

Comment: Keyword: "gray code".

Answer (score 2):

Encode your subsets as binary strings. Then, starting from the empty set $(0,0,0,\dots,0)$, start counting from 1 to $2^n$ and flip the bit corresponding to the lower $1$ in the binary expansion of your counter:

\begin{align}
000000 & \\
100000 &\text{(counter is $1$, flip leftmost bit)}\\
110000 &(\text{counter is $2$, flip second bit})\\
010000 &(\text{counter is $3$, flip leftmost bit again})\\
011000 &(\text{counter is $4$, flip third bit})\\
111000 &(5)\\
101000 &(6)\\
001000 &(7)\\
001100 &(8)\\
101100 &(9)
\end{align}

Comment: This seems like a nice solution. Can you explain further how you know which bit to flip? It looks like you flip leftmost every odd count, but how do you determine the even counts?

Comment: At n-th step, you write $n$ in binary, and flip the digit corresponding to the leftmost 1 in the number. Whe the counter is, for instance, $12$ (which is $1100$ in binary) you flip the third bit because the rightmost $1$ in the binary $12$ is in the third position from the right.

Answer (score 0):

A set of elements can be thought of equivocally as the binary string problem. Suppose your set is finite, with cardinality $n$. We know then that the power set has cardinality $2^{n}$. So set up a binary vector with $n$ elements. If there is a $1$ for a component, then the element is in the subset. Otherwise, it isn't.

Consider the set $\{A, B, C\}$.

The power set can be generated by the binary vectors, simply by counting in binary:
$$ 
(0, 0, 0), 
(0, 0, 1), 
(0, 1, 0), 
(0, 1, 1), 
(1, 0, 0), 
(1, 0, 1), 
(1, 1, 0), 
(1, 1, 1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

This really amounts to writing out a full binary tree of height $n$.

How would you do that? You would write a recursive program that says "given a tree of height $k$, let's write a tree of height $k+1$ by adding the top level nodes".

You fix some ordering of your set, then you traverse this order. Given the power set of the first $k$ elements, you obtain the power set of the $k+1$ elements by first applying mitosis, and duplicating the power set of the $k$ elements; then pick one of the copies, and add to all the entries the new element.

More specifically, here is some badly written recursive pseudo-code.

```
Power([1,k])
    if k=0 return Collection([1,0]) 
    else return Union(Power[0,k-1],Add(Power[0,k-1],{k}))

Add(A,B)
   return Collection(For each X in A collect Union(X,B))
```

Where `[1,k]` denotes the set $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, so `[1,0]` denotes the empty set.